Is there a way to add a calculated ( generated ) column in the database of a typo3 extension ext_tables.sql
Directly in MySQL, this is the column I need
ALTER TABLE my_extension ADD COLUMN `indexed-changed` INT AS (indexed - changed) STORED; 

Now to do it the TYPO3 way, I need to create this field in the ext_tables.sql of my extension so that the TYPO3 database analyser can update the database but it doesn't seems to work.
CREATE TABLE tx_solr_indexqueue_item (
    ...
    `changed` int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    `indexed` int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    `indexed-changed` int(11) AS (`indexed` - `changed`) STORED,
    ...

Gets me in the TYPO3 backend:
Database analysis failed
[SQL Error] line 0, col 564: Error: Expected NOT, NULL, DEFAULT, AUTO_INCREMENT, UNIQUE, PRIMARY, COMMENT, COLUMN_FORMAT, STORAGE or REFERENCES, got 'AS' in statement

Is there something I'm missing or another way to accomplish this?
EDIT:
The whole reason behind this is that my current query runs every minute and is taking way too much resources. And to be even more specific, it's the indexation scheduler task of https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/solr
Indexed and changed columns contains timestamps.
Before : ... WHERE changed > indexed

8 seconds to go through 900k records

After : ... WHERE indexed-changed < 0
( with an index on the indexed-changed column )

< 10 ms for the same records

In a nutshell, I'm trying to implement this solution the typo3 way : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107778/int-comparison-very-slow-in-query

Could you please specify what you want to achive? Because the MySQL statement you posted as explanation is not valid.

It is relatively inelegant to store redundant information in the database. A calculation based on two columns? IMO that belongs in the query rather than in an additional column...

I added some explanation to the original question

What you are looking for is a MySQL INDEX.
You must add your fields as a table index like this:
CREATE TABLE tx_solr_indexqueue_item (
    ...
    `changed` int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    `indexed` int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    INDEX `item_changed1_idx` (`changed`),
    INDEX `item_indexed1_idx` (`indexed`),
    ...
)

This should speed up your queries.
For more information about MySQL indexing in general see here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/mysql-indexes.html
And for more information about creating indexes see here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/create-index.html

Simply indexing the column doesn't help. What I need is a stored generated column : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

May be using an combined Index would speed up your query:
CREATE TABLE tx_solr_indexqueue_item (
    ...
    `changed` int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    `indexed` int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    INDEX `item_changed` (`changed`, `indexed`),
    ...
)

Regarding adding the column in TYPO3, I think thats not working because the Parser cannot handle AS XXX definitions:
https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/main/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/Schema/Parser/Parser.php#L585

I tried this but it doesn't help. As said in the answer of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107778/int-comparison-very-slow-in-query , INT comparisons cannot effectively use indexes.
